# Coolant level fluctuates too much

Tags: engine, coolant

I have a problem with the coolant level from my car (Renault 1.5 dCI engine). It fluctuates too much.

I left home with the coolant level at the minimum mark. After approximately 10 minutes I stopped the car and the level was above the maximum mark with approximately 2-3 centimeters (~1 inch). I started the engine once again and drove for about 5 minutes. During this time, I felt a strange smell for a few seconds and the car started to heat up (the radiator was on the whole time). I stopped the car once again and the level of the coolant was below minimum mark. Overnight, the level of the coolant rose again to the minimum mark.

I have recently changed the entire coolant, the lid of the expansion tank, and the thermostat but the problem still persists. There is no foam / bubbles in the coolant, there is no white smoke, the power of the engine has not changed, the oil looks fine.

Does anyone know what may cause this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I googled for bleed screws to vent excess air out of the cooling system on a Renault 1.5 dCI engine but saw so many contradictory images it'd be best if you looked at them to match them up with your exact engine. If there's air trapped inside the cooling system then hot spots can develop which allows steam to flash and cause pressure fluctuations which can create the problems you describe.